# K-means algorithm issue

Tags: java, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm trying to implement the K-means algorithm in Java on a list of latitudes and longitudes but getting incorrect cluster formation. I am not able to figure out what the error is.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
class KMeans
{
    static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
    {
        double x1=Math.abs(lat1-lat2);
        double y1=Math.abs(lon1-lon2);
        //System.out.println(dist);
        return (Math.sqrt((x1*x1)+(y1*y1)));
    }
    static double[] centroid(ArrayList<Double>[] g)  {
        double centroidX = 0, centroidY = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<g[0].size();i++)
        {
            centroidX+=g[0].get(i);
            centroidY+=g[1].get(i);
        }
        return new double[]{centroidX/g[0].size(),centroidY/g[0].size()};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File fo=new File("Places.txt");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(fo);
        double[][] a =new double[300][2];
        int l=0;
        StringBuilder lat= new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder lon= new StringBuilder();
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = myReader.nextLine();
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<data.length();i++)
            {
                if(data.charAt(i)==',')
                    break;
                lon.append(data.charAt(i));
            }
            for(i=i+1;i<data.length();i++)
            {
                lat.append(data.charAt(i));
            }
            a[l][0]=Double.parseDouble(lon.toString());
            a[l][1]=Double.parseDouble(lat.toString());
            l++;
            lat = new StringBuilder();
            lon = new StringBuilder();
        }
        ArrayList<Double>[] g1=new ArrayList[2];
        ArrayList<Double>[] g2=new ArrayList[2];
        ArrayList<Double>[] g3=new ArrayList[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            g1[i] = new ArrayList<Double>();
            g2[i] = new ArrayList<Double>();
            g3[i] = new ArrayList<Double>();
        }
        Random r=new Random();
        char[] cl;
        cl = new char[300];
        double[] x =a[2];
        double[] y =a[99];
        double[] z =a[270];
        double[] x1;
        double[] y1;
        double[] z1;
        double d1,d2,d3;
        while(true)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
                d1=distance(x[0],x[1],a[i][0],a[i][1]);
                d2=distance(y[0],y[1],a[i][0],a[i][1]);
                d3=distance(z[0],z[1],a[i][0],a[i][1]);
                if(d1<=d2&&d1<=d3)
                {
                    g1[0].add(a[i][0]);
                    g1[1].add(a[i][1]);
                    cl[i]='0';
                }
                else if(d2<=d1&&d2<=d3)
                {
                    g2[0].add(a[i][0]);
                    g2[1].add(a[i][1]);
                    cl[i]='1';
                }
                else
                {
                    g3[0].add(a[i][0]);
                    g3[1].add(a[i][1]);
                    cl[i]='2';
                }
            }
            x1=centroid(g1);
            y1=centroid(g2);
            z1=centroid(g3);
            if(x1[0]==x[0]&&x1[1]==x[1]&&y1[0]==y[0]&&y1[1]==y[1]&z1[0]==z[0]&&z1[1]==z[1])
                break;
            x[0]=x1[0];
            x[1]=x1[1];
            y[0]=y1[0];
            y[1]=y1[1];
            z[0]=z1[0];
            z[1]=z1[1];
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g1));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g2));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g3));
            g1[0].clear();
            g1[1].clear();
            g2[0].clear();
            g2[1].clear();
            g3[0].clear();
            g3[1].clear();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+" "+cl[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code and below is the file containing the list of latitudes and longitudes. Can someone please look into it and tell me where my code is failing to generate the desired output?

> -112.0707922,33.4516246
>   -112.0655423,33.4492979
>   -112.0739312,33.4564905
>   -112.0748658,33.4701155
>   -80.5256905,43.4770992
>   -80.5266413,43.4858748
>   -80.846495,35.225825
>   -112.0744277,33.4484911
>   -112.0731006,33.4299067
>   -80.8396357,35.2270542
>   -112.0738147,33.4487514
>   -80.84395,35.225394
>   -80.5361832,43.4722801
>   -112.0742828,33.4787931
>   -80.8404318988,35.2274789984
>   -80.8419989013,35.2283137726
>   -80.846935,35.22586
>   -112.074115,33.475583
>   -80.968306,35.283424
>   -80.5408376,43.484427
>   -80.527637205,43.5026116046
>   -80.5231354,43.4679471
>   -80.4937878,43.4894705
>   -80.8427865,35.2207294
>   -112.0686202,33.4521542
>   -80.5256905,43.4770992
>   -112.0696144,33.4523351
>   -80.5211216,43.4793516
>   -112.067518,33.4660304
>   -112.074326,33.46084
>   -80.5293258,43.49749
>   -80.843155,35.218214
>   -112.0686202,33.4521542
>   -112.0686777,33.4579128
>   -112.0657878,33.4768722
>   -80.8440182,35.2275943
>   -80.5203846,43.4787316
>   -112.0686202,33.4521542
>   -80.5256905,43.4770992
>   -80.8530782034,35.2260468097
>   -80.840783,35.23361
>   -80.8502645514,35.2336634617
>   -80.849647,35.223622
>   -80.8343082,35.2262527
>   -80.8411478,35.227822
>   -80.5377496406,43.4723280992
>   -112.0742162,33.4796505
>   -80.8500343,35.2341598
>   -112.0743321,33.4580837
>   -112.0721778,33.4663026
>   -80.5231407,43.4768135
>   -80.844616,35.223805
>   -112.065825,33.442472
>   -80.8670549,35.089035
>   -80.5238819,43.4648096
>   -80.84468,35.226433
>   -112.0655975,33.4653345
>   -80.7791381,35.0952753
>   -80.5392510355,43.4721726021
>   -80.843388,35.2279912
>   -112.072117722,33.4448019849
>   -80.5243892,43.4752375
>   -80.8414916,35.2278131
>   -112.0657286,33.4657117
>   -80.5230849,43.4677521
>   -80.846592,35.228193
>   -80.8456832,35.2223511
>   -112.0691069,33.4458023
>   -80.5227058,43.4670204
>   -80.843388,35.2279912
>   -80.5379276723,43.4722519425
>   -112.0717019,33.4483992
>   -80.8547192,35.2283983
>   -80.537082,43.471891
>   -112.0722009,33.4724737
>   -112.0750849,33.4685474
>   -112.073929,33.429424
>   -80.8464246,35.2246161
>   -80.5353761,43.4723904
>   -112.0657967,33.4365057
>   -112.0742794,33.4722371
>   -80.8419492,35.2262406
>   -112.0613638,33.4660928
>   -80.5232652,43.4692451
>   -112.0740375,33.4501458
>   -112.0255034,33.5303271
>   -80.5223045,43.4646939
>   -112.071886,33.449858
>   -80.5219541118,43.4628223628
>   -112.0744277,33.4484911
>   -80.536591,43.472091
>   -80.5377811566,43.4727816313
>   -112.0699472,33.4506843
>   -80.5244182,43.486349
>   -80.5246119,43.4646469
>   -80.5409781,43.5071296
>   -80.8473278,35.2239303
>   -80.8394745,35.2278411
>   -112.0996404,33.5176328
>   -112.0705878,33.4500609
>   -112.0706266,33.4450359
>   -80.519187,43.4772196
>   -112.0678078,33.4585108
>   -112.0740511,33.4499524
>   -80.847333,35.234098
>   -80.847,35.217205
>   -112.070122,33.443909
>   -80.5398649,43.4691285
>   -112.0772,33.449188
>   -112.070655,33.4555253
>   -80.5273068,43.463366
>   -80.8426239,35.2284099
>   -112.0740962,33.4794824
>   -80.5371146277,43.4725006073
>   -112.072706876,33.4483756752
>   -112.0686337,33.4516878
>   -80.5182138,43.483281
>   -112.0656044,33.4372015
>   -80.5194703,43.476998
>   -80.528095,43.474541
>   -80.8421891375,35.2247714304
>   -80.8414916,35.2278131
>   -112.0736968,33.476644
>   -80.5137443,43.471126
>   -80.8480944,35.056435
>   -80.5233044,43.4679985
>   -80.84581,35.214505
>   -80.5381164327,43.4721891678
>   -80.8393449,35.2216474
>   -80.5235285,43.4636098
>   -80.838659,35.228234
>   -80.5545309,43.5093982
>   -80.851868,35.233064
>   -112.0737923,33.4568607
>   -112.0741097,33.4505535
>   -80.5183755,43.4782831
>   -80.52628,43.484483
>   -112.0686202,33.4521542
>   -112.0737003,33.4757646
>   -80.5178879,43.4758781
>   -80.84395,35.225394
>   -80.8449462,35.225705
>   -112.0709775,33.4470733
>   -80.5221597,43.4642893
>   -80.8464728,35.2240131
>   -80.84104,35.2244979
>   -80.8411478,35.227822
>   -112.073569,33.4640982988
>   -80.841786,35.2340477
>   -80.8174063386,35.0578530619
>   -80.5193889,43.4596341
>   -80.8439988,35.2329575
>   -80.809002,35.220697
>   -80.523446,43.4667473
>   -80.5365122,43.4720116
>   -80.5238087,43.466708
>   -80.5250886,43.477593
>   -80.5228895,43.467046
>   -80.857545,35.117183
>   -80.783798,35.096526
>   -80.527828,43.489061
>   -112.0696051,33.464388
>   -80.5351869,43.5030738
>   -112.0709775,33.4470733
>   -80.843388,35.2279912
>   -80.53118,43.502488
>   -80.5213927,43.4659522
>   -80.521901,43.4647024
>   -80.5249727,43.4845752
>   -80.5243842,43.5048639
>   -80.5373674259,43.4730259144
>   -112.070585498,33.4507074659
>   -112.074248,33.47626
>   -80.922732,35.237471
>   -80.849538,35.227078
>   -112.074802052,33.448424817
>   -80.5364492,43.4720225
>   -80.8428142,35.2265794
>   -80.845804,35.2263469
>   -80.5223193,43.4648949
>   -112.06909,33.46544
>   -80.555717,43.452243
>   -80.8319153,35.1879068
>   -80.8530782034,35.2260468097
>   -80.5391085148,43.4719665363
>   -80.8401304,35.2273178
>   -80.843388,35.2279912
>   -80.5243892,43.4752375
>   -112.073577,33.44455
>   -80.5260902,43.483456
>   -80.8461559,35.22533
>   -80.844191,35.226995
>   -112.0736854,33.4793911
>   -112.071322,33.449909
>   -112.073417,33.477939
>   -80.845006058,35.2286502258
>   -112.06649,33.4667869
>   -112.0741767,33.4558849
>   -80.8411478,35.227822
>   -112.081565,33.465499
>   -80.5252447306,43.4763190134
>   -112.0739284,33.4739691
>   -80.851336,35.238088
>   -112.074153,33.46425
>   -80.538629,43.472371
>   -80.9405309,35.239674
>   -112.072914,33.477594
>   -80.531231,43.5028859
>   -80.84119,35.228915
>   -80.728384,35.2771265
>   -80.537061,43.472566
>   -80.839671,35.228985
>   -80.8473,35.230158
>   -112.0686202,33.4521542
>   -80.5221353,43.4657569
>   -80.5211055,43.4793595
>   -112.0736809,33.4794762
>   -80.5388363109,43.4717869083
>   -112.0741467,33.4633319
>   -80.5210309,43.462251
>   -112.072092,33.47066
>   -80.5217836,43.4629195
>   -80.5222866,43.4610385
>   -80.536591,43.471998
>   -80.8394131,35.2302318
>   -80.844683,35.223866
>   -80.8416248,35.2286559
>   -112.0741767,33.4558849
>   -80.828252,35.1467079
>   -112.073106,33.473847
>   -112.0686202,33.4521542
>   -80.842303,35.226746
>   -80.84547,35.224456
>   -80.536612,43.472091
>   -80.5318027,43.4991122
>   -80.843784,35.2275289
>   -112.0712574,33.4484654
>   -80.8461559,35.22533
>   -112.071075886,33.4468850573
>   -80.8412724,35.2288472
>   -112.0664327,33.476323
>   -112.0744277,33.4484911
>   -80.8381685,35.2310911
>   -80.8464246,35.2246161
>   -80.8424708,35.2292799
>   -80.8393335,35.2250606
>   -80.840985,35.228281
>   -80.8396379,35.231684
>   -80.834638,35.228506
>   -112.0740373,33.4483771
>   -80.8464728,35.2240131
>   -80.8388937,35.2274621
>   -80.5238819,43.4648096
>   -80.53827703,43.4725940388
>   -80.5365704,43.471988
>   -80.5250037834,43.4774177316
>   -80.8489878,35.2335751
>   -112.0674357,33.4503971
>   -80.8407079,35.2172053
>   -112.0744197,33.4771144
>   -80.5353761,43.4723904
>   -112.0865171,33.4547647
>   -80.8406527,35.2274197
>   -80.5274971,43.4980824
>   -80.5408262,43.4844189
>   -112.0732082,33.5087398
>   -80.5184485,43.4657108
>   -112.07194,33.4493093
>   -80.5228895,43.467046
>   -112.074558593,33.4492572677
>   -80.529250574,43.5037624514
>   -80.8361303,35.2327235
>   -112.0743321,33.4580837
>   -80.8452366,35.2254586
>   -80.5253004,43.4763761
>   -80.5224956,43.4697612
>   -112.073481,33.439268
>   -112.066333,33.450875
>   -80.5150582,43.4703532
>   -80.5229421,43.4667083
>   -80.84104,35.2244979
>   -80.84972,35.21873
>   -80.8414487,35.227987
>   -80.851151,35.220527
>   -80.5223735,43.4639601
>   -80.5247756,43.4770643
>   -80.8473977,35.2215512
>   -80.5551852,43.5064923
>   -80.5361832,43.4722801
>   -112.0736806,33.4794817
>   -80.5393988,43.5011946
>   -112.0789482,33.4800317
>   -80.864092,35.093322
>   -112.0705438,33.4657432
>   -80.5178155,43.4755885
>   -112.0732961,33.479418
>   -112.0669197,33.4670273
>   -112.0733849,33.4691037
>   -80.5340476,43.4728924
>   -112.0693184,33.4657177

Comment: 1. What is the desired output?  2. What is the error you're facing? Is it undesired output? Is it a compilation error? Is it a runtime exception?

Comment: The format of the output is correct. It seems to be a logical error. I am said that the cluster formation is wrong.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this algorithm, but for the benefit of someone who does, I believe it'd be useful if you posted what output you're getting and what would be the correct output to compare it against. I have found a couple of resources that might be helpful. [Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-means-clustering-introduction/) and this [blog post](https://medium.com/@tarlanahad/a-friendly-introduction-to-k-means-clustering-algorithm-b31ff7df7ef1). I hope those help you out.